# How to extract GIS domains from geodatabases in R?

Tags: r, gis, arcgis

Does anyone know how to read in domains from file geodatabases? I've been extracting the domains manually via ArcCatalog's Domain to Table tool, and then reading in the created table, but I'm sure there's a way to skip the middle man. I can read in feature classes fine using the rgdal and sf packages, but it doesn't seem to recognize any of the multiple domains in the file. Below is an example using the STRUCT_Alabama_State_GDB.gdb [found here](https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Struct/GDB/STRUCT_Alabama_State_GDB.zip).

```
library(rgdal)    
fc_list = ogrListLayers("STRUCT_Alabama_State_GDB.gdb")
print(fc_list)
```

The output of above code just lists the 4 layers in the geodatabase ("Struct_Point" "BPFeatureToMetadata" "Meta_DatasetDetail"  "Meta_ProcessDetail"), but none of the existing attribute domains that can be viewed in ArcCatalog (e.g., Distribution_Policy Domain, Education FCode, Health and Medical FCode, etc.). I've tried using the following code as well to extract specific domain tables with no luck:

```
library(sf)
gdal_metadata("STRUCT_Alabama_State_GDB.gdb", domain_item = "Education FCode")
```

> Error in gdal_metadata("STRUCT_Alabama_State_GDB.gdb", 
>   :domain_item[1](https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Struct/GDB/STRUCT_Alabama_State_GDB.zip) not found in available metadata domains

Comment: It may be hard to get a good answer without an actually-available `example.gdb` that reproduces the behavior in question

Comment: Thanks, I added some real data and more detail of what I've tried so far.